# how i will compare string value with a nsmutablearray

Tags: objective-c

```
if ([pArray objectAtIndex:2]==@"ROOT")
{
    NSLog(@"YES");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"NO");
}
```

I am using this code but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use isEqualToString: method:

```
if ([[pArray objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"ROOT"]){
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
- (BOOL)containsObject:(id)anObject;
```

to check if the object is in the array.
eg. `[pArray containsObject:@"ROOT"];`

if you need to check if particular element is equal to a string you can use.

```
[[pArray objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"ROOT"];
```

Both will return YES if matched.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming pArray contains strings... use the following...

```
if([[pArray objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"ROOT"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the isEqualToString method. You are attempting to compare two references in your statement.

```
if ([[pArray objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"ROOT"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (([pArray objectAtIndex:2]  != (id)[NSNull null])&([[pArray objectAtIndex:2] isEqual:@"ROOT"])){
        NSLog(@"String in array is %@",[pArray objectAtIndex:2]);
    }
    else {
       if([pArray objectAtIndex:2]  == (id)[NSNull null]){
        NSLog(@"Your Object is Null");
       }
else{
   NSLog(@"Your Object does not match");
}   
}
```